# Binding a JSF bean to a included JSF

Tags: jsf, facelets, backing-beans

I'm at the end of my rope with this one. I'm new to JSF so this is probably my misunderstanding of a lot of stuff.

```
<ui:composition>
    <f:view>
         <tr:form>
             <ui:fragment rendered="#{param['type'] eq 'myType'}">
                <ui:include src="/home/myPage.jspx" />
            </ui:fragment>
        ......
```

I pass the page a certain type, it display's certain fields/criteria for a form and a bean backs it all because there is a single search.

Within myPage.jspx I have:

```
action="#{MyBean.submitForm}"
```

does not work, although a onsubmit="alert('hi');" does work as an attribute of the form element.

I guess what's most confusing is that

```
valueChangeListener="#{MyBean.stateChanged}"
```

does work on a field in the myPage.jspx

Why does the action (attribute of a button) not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During processing of the form submit, if the button or one of its parent components is not `rendered`, then the button's action won't be invoked. You need to make sure that the `rendered` attribute evaluates the same during processing of the form submit as it did when the form was displayed. In your case, you're depending on the value of a request parameter with the name `type`.

In this particular case, you could solve the problem by retaining the request parameter `type` by a `<f:param>` nested in the command button:

```
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:param name="type" value="#{param.type}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Or, if you're using JSF 2.0, placing the bean in the view scope and setting the `type` parameter in the managed bean by `<f:viewParam>` can also solve it.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="type" value="#{bean.type}" />
</f:metadata>

...

<ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.type eq 'myType'}">
```

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

Comment: You were certainly spot on with the reason it was failing. The parameter is being lost. I tried doing the f:param option but that didn't work, said the Servlet couldn't set the param (can't remember exact error). What I eventually did was set the param on the backing bean in the beans constructor: 'HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
  type = req.getParameter("myType");'             then I just edited the #{} to check the property. Thanks also for the url I wish my searching had turned that up a day ago!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, `ExternalContext` has a `getRequestParameterMap()` method which gives you the parameter map back without the need to have any single line of `javax.servlet` import in your JSF backing bean (which is a sign of code smell).